# Difficulty Understanding Nested functions in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm still trying to understand the basics of Python and am trying to figure out how to attach a value to `y` in the inner function `action2`.

```
def outer(n):
def action(x):
    return x ** n
    def action2(y):
        return x/n
    return action2
return action

f = outer(2) #We are actually setting the n in action here
print(f)
print(f(5)) #We are now setting the x parameter in the inner function action 
print(f(4))

g = outer(3)
print(g(3))

print(f(3)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't because `action` always returns in the line before that.

Comment: In the third line, the function `action` returns `x ** n`, and everything after that on the same indentation level and below isn't ever executed.  Also, is it intentional that you divide `x` by `n` without actually using the parameter `y`?

Comment: I suspect that your code is not properly formatted, should I be right could you please fix the code in your Q?

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for nesting functions like this is for function decoration. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797471/context-manager-to-validate-data) a few months ago, and one of the answers seems to fit almost perfectly for your use case. Essentially you're trying to do this:

```
def outer(n):
    def action(x):
        def action2(y):
            return x**n / y
        return action2
    return action
```

Which is a bit of a strange way to do

```
def action(n, x, y):
    return x**n / y
```

But we'll roll with it. In any case, let's return to our canonical function decorator and see how it compares.

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Calling inner function")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@decorator
def foo(some_txt):
    print("Hello, ", some_txt)

# EXAMPLE OUTPUT
>>> foo("World!")
Calling inner function
Hello, World!
```

This is one layer too shallow for what you're trying to do. If we return back to the question I linked earlier on, we'll talk about a validator.

```
max_len_12 = lambda n: len(n) <= 12 # 12 character max field length

def validation(v):
    """ensures the result of func passes a validation defined by v"""
    def outer(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            while True:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                # if validation passes
                if v(result):
                    return result
        return inner
    return outer

@validation(max_len_12)
def valid_input(prompt):
    return input(prompt)

# EXAMPLE
>>> valid_input("Enter your name (max 12 chars): ")
Enter your name (max 12 chars): Adam YouBetYourAss Smith
Enter your name (max 12 chars): Adam Smith
'Adam Smith'
```

Or more easily:

```
valid_input = validation(max_len_12)(raw_input)
# same as previous function
```

Since it's difficult to know EXACTLY what it is you're trying to do from your example code, hopefully this gives you a good leg to stand on when it comes to decorators and closures. Note that there's a whole world of things you have to do to make your functions introspectable, most of which can be taken care of by [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to accomplish the following:

```
def outer(n):
    def action(x):
        def action2(y):
            return x ** n / y
        return action2
    return action
```

Now, your test commands give:

```
>>> f = outer(2)
>>> print f
<function action at 0x7f59b872e578>
>>> print f(5)
<function action2 at 0x7f59b872e5f0>
>>> print f(4)
<function action2 at 0x7f59b872e5f0>
```

`f` is your outer “closure”, which is itself a “factory” function returning your inner closure.

```
>>> g = outer(3)
>>> print g(3)
<function action2 at 0x7f59b872e668>
```

You now have two completely independent functions `f` and `g`.

```
>>> print f(3)
<function action2 at 0x7f59b872e668>
```

…and you can continue using `f` as before, which is probably not what you intended to do.

You can call the inner closure like this:

```
>>> f5 = f(5)
>>> print f5(10.)
2.5
```

Or you can completely skip the variables:

```
>>> outer(3)(10)(2)
500
```