# Python Tkinter text entry validation using colors

Tags: python, validation, textbox, tkinter

I am new to Python and Tkinter, and am trying to validate a numeric text entry using colors indicating(black = valid entry; blue = valid, default value; red = invalid entry).  I can do this explicitly for each entry using the following code:

```
pdef = 14.7
p = 60

Label(parent, text="Pressure").grid(in_=frame_a,row=3, column=2, sticky='e')
p_entry = Entry(parent, width=8 ,textvariable=p, fg = pcolor)
p_entry.grid(in_=frame_a,row=3, column=3, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='we', columnspan=1)
p_entry.bind("<FocusOut>", validate)

def validate(event):
   global pcolor
   pmax = 30000
   pmin = 0
   y = p.get()

   if y == pdef:
       pcolor = 'blue'
   elif y < pmin or y > pmax:
       pcolor = 'red'
   else:
      pcolor = 'black'
   p_entry.config(fg = pcolor)  # explicitly set text color in p_entry textbox
   return(pcolor)
```

However, I now see the value in taking an object oriented approach, where I can pass the current, high, low and default values to a validate method and return a flag which can be one of 3 values.  The problem is that I can't see how to apply an action color to the text based on the value returned in a generalized rather than explicit way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mack

[EDIT]

Thanks Adam.  Your first example shows just what I want to do.  However, I would like for the validate function to be used for various instances of the text box validation.  I have adapted the code based on your suggested partial function.  Here is what I have ...

```
self.p['p_e'] = StringVar()
self.p['p_e'].set(14.7)       # Pressure

self.p_entry = Entry(root, width=8 ,textvariable=self.p['p_e'], fg = pcolor)
self.p_entry.bind("<FocusOut>", partial(self.color_changer,name = 'p_entry',
    y = float(self.p['p_e'].get()),max = 30000, min = 0, dft = 14.7))

def color_changer(self,event,name,y,max,min,dft):
   """entry validation Blue=default, Black=User, Red=Out of Range"""

   def validator(value):

      if value == dft:
         return -1
      elif value < min or value > max:
         return 0

   result = validator(y)          
   if result == -1:
      self.p_entry.config(fg = 'blue')
   elif result == 0:
      self.p_entry.config(fg = 'red')
   else:
      self.p_entry.config(fg = 'black')
```

I still have a couple problems:
1) the field value passed to the color change function is the initialized value, rather than the edited value when the `<FocusOut>` event is triggered
2) I am not sure how to replace `self.p_entry.config` (hardcoded above) with a general variable (I pass'name') tied to the text entry instance

Any help appreciated!
Thanks,
Mack

Comment: I don't know what you mean RE: #1, but IIRC for #2: the `Event` object has an attribute that identifies what object triggered the event called `widget`. I'm not on a system that has Python installed atm, but try `self.event.widget.config(fg = 'blue')` and etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
from functools import partial
PMIN, PMAX = 0, 30000

def color_changer(event, pmin, pmax):

    def validator(value):
        if value < pmin:
            return -1
        if value > pmax:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    pressure = p.get()
    result = validator(pressure)
    if result == 0:
       p_entry.config(fg='black')
    else:
       p_entry.config(fg='red')

p_entry.bind("<FocusOut", partial(color_changer, pmin=PMIN, pmax=PMAX))
```

Your other option may be to create a closure that produces a validation function, and use that in your callback. Something like:

```
from functools import partial

def validation_wrapper(test):
    def wrapped(value):
        return test(value)
    return wrapped

def color_changer(event, validation_test):
    pressure = p.get()
    result = validation_wrapper(validation_test)(pressure)
    if result:
        p_entry.config(fg='black')
    else:
        p_entry.config(fg='red')

between_min_and_max = lambda x: PMIN <= x <= PMAX
p_entry.bind("<FocusOut>", partial(color_changer, validation_test=between_min_and_max))
```

I actually [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797471/context-manager-to-validate-data) that produced an answer quite similar to this approach not too long.