# Python Password Checker

Tags: python

I need some help figuring out how to make a function that checks a string for a bunch of conditions.

- Passwords must    be  at  least   5   characters  long
- Passwords must contain at least one upper case letter
- Passwords must    contain at  least   two numbers
- Passwords may not contain the characters  "E" or  "e"
- Passwords must    include at  least   one special symbol:     !,  @,  #,  $,  %,  ^,  &

right now this is all that I have

```
def passwordChecker(password):
    '''
    '''
    caps = sum(1 for c in password if c.isupper())
    nums = sum(1 for c in password if c.isdigit())
    symb = any(c in password for c in '!@#$%^&')
    note = any(c in password for c in 'Ee')
    if len(password) <5:
        return False
    elif caps < 1:
        return False
    elif nums < 1:
        return False
    elif symb == False:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Edit**

Just realized that I have to check also if there are commonly used passwords like 'password' or '111111' and I dont really know about how I would approach this.

Comment: You forgot to check for `note == False`

Comment: and `nums` should be `nums < 2` instead

Comment: You'll need to identify what values qualify as commonly-used passwords, and then check for them.

Comment: its asking for specific strings though

Comment: Yes; define some commonly-used passwords (with a `list`, `set`, etc.) and then check whether `password in common_passwords`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative using regular expressions:

```
import re
def passwordChecker(password):
    return all(re.search(pattern, password) for pattern in
               ('.{5}', '[A-Z]', '\d.*\d', '^[^Ee]*$', '[!@#$%^&]'))
```

Demo using five barely invalid and five barely valid tests (one invalid and one valid for each of the five rules):

```
for password in ('1A!',   '12!34', 'A1bc!', 'A12E!', 'A12bc',
                 '1A!2.', 'A2!34', 'A12c!', 'A12b!', 'A12b@'):
    print(passwordChecker(password))
```

Prints `False` for the first five and `True` for the last five.

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing a branch

```
elif note:
    return False
```

before the `else:`

Comment: I am always getting a return of false which is what i can't figure out

Comment: I tried your original code as well as with this addition, and I don't always get `False`. Maybe you're not picking an acceptable password?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to talk about decorators! I *love* using decorators to validate data, [probably too much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798769/3058609). You could make validators for all that, and wrap it around your `get_password` method.

```
def v_length(password):
    return len(password) >= 5
def v_upper(password):
    return password.lower() != password
def v_2_nums(password):
    return sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) >= 2
def v_no_e(password):
    return "e" not in password.lower()
def v_specialchar(password):
    any(s in password for s in "!@#$%^&")

def validator(*tests):
    def wrap(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if not all(test(result) for test in tests):
                # fail the input somehow -- how??
            return result
        return wrapped
    return wrap

@validator(v_length, v_upper, v_2_nums, v_no_e, v_specialchar)
def get_password():
    pwd = input("Enter your password: ")
```

I like to wrap my validators in their own factories when I do this in real code, so that it's easier to change per application

```
def v_length(min_length):
    def wrapped(password):
        return len(password) >= min_length
    return wrapped

@validator(v_length(8))
def get_weak_password():
    input("Enter your wussy password: ")

@validator(v_length(64))
def get_strong_password():
    input("Enter your Herculean password: ")
```

This second approach works well for checking for common passwords.

```
def v_common(common_pwd_set):
    def wrapped(password):
        return password not in common_pwd_set
    return wrapped

COMMON_PASSWORDS = {"hunter2", "111111", "password"}
@validator(v_common(COMMON_PASSWORDS))
def get_password():
    pwd = input("Use a tricksy one! ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following checks for each failure condition, with short-circuiting (it'll stop checking once it finds something). The "common" passwords aren't really common, but I wanted values that would pass the rest of the checks.

```
def passwordChecker(password):
    '''
    A password checker. Returns True if the password is acceptable; False otherwise.
    '''
    if (len(password) < 5 or
        not any(c.isupper() for c in password) or
        sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) < 2 or
        'e' in password.lower() or
        not (set(password) & set('!@#$%^&')) or
        password in {'Password12!', 'Passwd12!'}):
        return False
    return True
```

---

```
>>> passwordChecker('Password12!')
False
>>> passwordChecker('hi')
False
>>> passwordChecker('H12!')
False
>>> passwordChecker('Hi12!')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do this...

```
def passwordChecker(password):
    return (len(password) > 4 and
            len(filter(str.isupper, password)) > 0 and
            len(filter(str.isdigit, password)) > 1 and
            'e' not in password.lower() and
            any(special in password for special in '!@#$%^&') and
            password not in ('password', '111111'))
```

I think the most interesting part of my solution is the use of `filter`; some people like it, others hate it. Anyway, all of the other solutions work just as well. Just thought I'd throw this one into the mix for completeness.